# What is the equivalent of %%~nxD in Bash?

Tags: bash, batch-file

I'm working on converting some batch scripts into a bash script to build a project on Linux and I need to convert `%%~nxD` to Bash. It is used in the following form:

```
FOR %%D IN ("%SOURCE_DIR%\..\..") DO SET "ProjName=%%~nxD"
```

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does it do in batch ?

Comment: Please put what it does in DOS/batch when you ask how to do it in another language.

Comment: http://batsh.org provides some ability to convert between bat->sh and sh->bat. It flags your `VarName= ....` as having a syntax error. *Maybe* if you paste the whole script there, you'll get a better result. Good luck.

Comment: This is the line from the batch file that I am trying to convert.                        FOR %%D IN ("%SOURCE_DIR%\..\..") DO SET "ProjName=%%~nxD"

Comment: Yeah, we guessed that, but needed would be someone who knows both (a) what it means in batch and (b) how to write it in bash - we thought you could at least provide the first half of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> FOR %%D IN ("%SOURCE_DIR%\..\..") DO SET "ProjName=%%~nxD"
> ```

(Assuming that is to find the third path component of the `SOURCE_DIR` variable.)

In bash, that might look like this:

```
ProjName=$(basename `(cd $SOURCE_DIR/../..; pwd)`)
```

(`cd` - change into the directory, `pwd` - print the current directory, `basename` - take the last component of the name.)

Alternatively:

```
ProjName=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $SOURCE_DIR)))
```

(Strip two path components with the `dirname`, then take the last component with the `basename`.)

or, without extra commands (fast, but ugly):

```
TEMP1=${SOURCE_DIR%/*/*}
ProjName=${TEMP1##*/}
```

(The same as previous, but using the bash' built-in string expansion. Search `man bash` for `##` - it would lead you directly to the string expansion description.)

The major differences between the options are:

- The first is ugly, but IME the most reliable, and thanks to the `pwd` can be used to resolve the symlinks. (Also allows for error checking.)
- The second simulates the `../..` with nested `dirname` calls.
- The third does the same as second, but is faster since it doesn't use the commands, but string expansion instead. But it has a flaw that if `$SOURCE_DIR` ends with a redundant `/`, it might not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing since you didn't add what it does in DOS that you want the parent directory?

```
var=${PWD%*/}
```

if it's the current directory, no path

```
var=${PWD##/*}
```